# JQuery - Select exact class structure

Tags: jquery, html, css, class

I am working on some functionality for a website. I am designing, and I am kind of stuck on something small. I want to hide divs that contain an exact class structure.

For example, if I give it the class selector "`.class1.class2.class3`", it will ONLY hide elements that have exact class structure. What I am doing now would hide elements like "`.class1.class2.class3.class4`", and I don't want that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean that the `.class1.class2.class3` object has no other class names?  Or what exact criteria makes it not a match?  You haven't defined the problem well enough to offer a code solution yet.

Answer (score 3):

In this particular case, you can use the [.not() selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/):

```
$('.class1.class2.class3:not(.class4)')
```

You can also do it with method chaining:

```
$('.class1.class2.class3').not('.class4')
```

*Note that this doesn't necessarily select exactly `.class1.class2.class3` with no other classes, it just prevents anything with `class4` from being selected.*

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for!

Could I also do something like
`:not(.class4.class5)`

I assume that would be kosher, but just for reference!

Comment: @Giovonni, yes, you can put any selector inside `:not()`. So `:not(.class4.class5)` will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

I you want to match objects that ONLY have exactly those three class names and you want to be insensitive to the order of the class names or the amount of white space between them, then you can do it like this:

```
$('.class1.class2.class3').filter(function() {
     return(this.className.replace(/class1|class2|class3/g, "").replace(/\s*/g, "") == '');
});
```

If you want to only exclude a specific other class, then you can do it like this:

```
$('.class1.class2.class3').not('.class4')
```